# How to make an array of child objects

Tags: java, arrays, object, subclass

I have an assignment from my professor and I can't figure out how to properly create an array of objects. None of the classes but the Client class can be changed; the interface can't be changed either. I'm supposed to be able to create an array of objects from several subclasses and be able to access all of the methods.

Here is my error report:

```
MathewBorumP5.java:68: error: cannot find symbol
                    revenue = movies[x].calcRevenue();
                                       ^
symbol:   method calcRevenue()
location: class Movie
MathewBorumP5.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
                            movies[x].getYear(), movies[x].calcRevenue(),
                                                          ^
symbol:   method calcRevenue()
location: class Movie
MathewBorumP5.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
                            movies[x].calcProfit(revenue), movies[x].categor
y());
                                     ^
symbol:   method calcProfit(double)
location: class Movie
MathewBorumP5.java:71: error: cannot find symbol
                            movies[x].calcProfit(revenue), movies[x].categor
y());
                                                                    ^
symbol:   method category()
location: class Movie
MathewBorumP5.java:78: error: cannot find symbol
                    totalRevenue = totalRevenue + movies[x].calcRevenue();
                                                           ^
symbol:   method calcRevenue()
location: class Movie
MathewBorumP5.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
                    "%.3f million dollars.", Movie[0].getTotalMovies(), tota
lRevenue);
                                             ^
symbol:   variable Movie
location: class MathewBorumP5
6 errors
```

**My client class:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathewBorumP5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int choice;
        boolean restart = true;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Movie[] movies = new Movie[6];
        movies[0] = new Animated("Beauty and the Beast", "Gary Trousdale", 1991,
            10.0, 5.0, 2.0);
        movies[1] = new Animated("Peter Pan", "Clyde Geronimi", 1953, 2.0, 1.2,
            .5);
        movies[2] = new Documentary("Planet Earth", "Alastair Fothergill", 2006,
            10, 20, 5);
        movies[3] = new Documentary("Drain the Ocean", "Steve Nichols", 2009, 9,
            2,3);
        movies[4] = new Drama("The Shawshank Redemption", "Frank Darabont",
            1994, 89, 7, 2);
        movies[5] = new Drama("The Godfather", "Francis Coppola", 1972, 10, 3,
            5);

        do {
            menu();
            System.out.print("Enter a number from 1 - 5: ");
            choice = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("\n");

            switch(choice) {
                case 1:
                    item1(movies);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    item2(movies);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    restart = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("You didn't enter a number between 1"
                        + " and 5.\n");
                    break;
            }
        } while(restart == true);
    }

    public static void menu() {
        System.out.print("Warren Moore Movie Menu\n");
        System.out.print("1. Show the list of movies in the array\n");
        System.out.print("2. Display the total number of movies and the total" +
            " revenues\n");
        System.out.print("3. Search movie by title\n");
        System.out.print("4. Display movies sorted by profit in decreasing" +
            " order\n");
        System.out.print("5. Exit\n");
    }

    public static void item1(Movie[] movies) {
        double revenue;
        System.out.printf("%-26s%-6s%-10s%-9s%-11s\n", "Title", "Year", 
        "Revenue", "Profit", "Category");
        for(int x = 0; x <= 6; x++) {
            revenue = movies[x].calcRevenue();              
                System.out.printf("%-26s%-6s%-10s%-9s%-11s\n", movies[x].getTitle(),
                movies[x].getYear(), movies[x].calcRevenue(),
                movies[x].calcProfit(revenue), movies[x].category());
        }
    }

    public static void item2(Movie[] movies) {
        double totalRevenue;
        for(int x = movies[0].getTotalMovies(); x > 0; x--) {
            totalRevenue = totalRevenue + movies[x].calcRevenue();
        }
        printf("The total number of moves is %d, and their total revenue is" +
            "%.3f million dollars.", Movie[0].getTotalMovies(), totalRevenue);
    }
}
```

**My Superclass:**

```
public class Movie {
    protected String title;
    protected String director;
    protected int year;
    protected double productionCost;
    private static int totalMovies = 0;

    public Movie() {
        totalMovies++;
    }
    public Movie(String newTitle, String newDirector, int newYear,
        double newCost) {
        totalMovies++;
        title = newTitle;
        director = newDirector;
        year = newYear;
        productionCost = newCost;
    }

    public int getTotalMovies() {
        return totalMovies;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public double getProductionCost() {
        return productionCost;
    }

    public void setProductionCost(double productionCost) {
        this.productionCost = productionCost;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Class template(all my classes are basically the same):

```
public class Animated extends Movie implements Profitable {
    private double rate;
    private double income;

    public Animated() {
        super();
    }

    public Animated(String title, String director, int year, double cost,
        double rate, double income) {
        super(title, director, year, cost);
        this.rate = rate;
        this.income = income;
    }

    public double getRate() {
        return rate;
    }

    public void setRate(double rate) {
        this.rate = rate;
    }

    public double getIncome() {
        return income;
    }

    public void setIncome(double income) {
        this.income = income;
    }

    public String category() {
        return "Animated";
    }

    public double calcRevenue() {
        return (income * rate);
    }

    public double calcProfit(double revenue) {
        return (revenue - super.productionCost);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return (super.toString() + "");
    }
}
```

**My interface:**

```
public interface Profitable {
    public abstract String category();
    public abstract double calcRevenue();
    public abstract double calcProfit(double revenue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add appropriate cast and test using instanceof.

```
revenue = movies[x].calcRevenue();
```

must be replaced by

```
if (movies[x] instanceof Profitable) {
  revenue = ((Profitable)movies[x]).calcRevenue();
} else {
  // decide what to do if movie if not profitable that is to say does not have the calcRevenue method
}
```